# Connecting Client/Server program outside of LAN with Python

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, firewall

I am trying to create a chess game between two different computers that are not in the same LAN. I am having trouble connecting the two via a TCP connection (UDP would probably be sufficient as well if the packets are arriving, but ideally TCP).

I am new to a lot of networking and am unaware of many different tools that may be useful and I am also in university and therefore don't have control over the router to update firewall rules. What can I do to work around the router firewall to connect the two devices.

I am primarily using the Python socket library at the moment to implement the connection.

Any information about how I can send messages between the two computers outside of a LAN would be very useful. Thank you for your help!

I have ensured that the client side is using the public IP of the server and the server is using "" for its socket host. I also checked that the connection was working when utilizing a LAN without issue. I included a batch file that enables the specific port used for the game at the beginning of runtime and disables it at the end of the program. If I am not mistaken, that only impacts the computer's firewall rules not the router's. I have looked into receive the packets through port 80 and redirecting it to my specific program, but was unsuccesful in finding a solution of that type.

Comment: Is your server behind a firewall?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it is behind my school's router which has a firewall that is not visible to me. I can scan it for open ports from a separate computer though. The computer firewall itself is windows defender firewall which shouldn't be relevant because the batch file should allow the port to send and receive packets.

Comment: If you don't have access or can change the outer firewall, then there's really nothing you can do to allow clients from outside.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is it not possible to create a sort of forwarding table through an allowed port such as port 80? How do other applications take care of this by default. For most applications, I do not remember having to update router settings (on home router, not university), how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the server is behind a router/firewall you'll have to use some sort of [hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) method to create the connection. [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) is one of the most common, though I've never actually used it in a Python program so I don't know what Python implementations are out there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction, it looks like the right idea, but based on what I read requires an additional STUN server outside of the NAT which I do not have unfortunately. How do video games for example accomplish this goal? Any game on steam is able to communicate through the router and must be in some form getting through the firewall. I haven't been able to find much information on how this is accomplished.

Comment: Games that use p2p connections these days will start by trying to make a direct connection but often have to fallback to STUN or some other NAT traversal technique such as TURN for many clients because so many people are behind symmetric NATs now. Steam has a huge network of relay servers for this exact purpose, and provides an API for developers to facilitate setting up the connections.

I know there are quite a few free STUN/TURN server lists out there. You could try using one of those if you don't want to set up your own.